# Proper mechanism to add elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to add elements dynamically to a dropdown but I think I'm mixing syntaxes and would like to go pure jQuery.  Currently I'm doing this:

`$("#data-source-menu").addClass("menu-container")
                       .html($("<ul class=\"popup-menu\" id=\"dataset-menu\"><\/ul>"));`

Then later

`$("#dataset-menu").append($("<div>" + dataset.label + "<\/div>").addClass("menu-item").attr(dataset));`

It's that inner building of the html I don't like.  Is there a more abstract way to approach this that doesn't involve writing html?  Something like JavaScript's `document.createTextNode("Hello")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be better:

```
$('#data-source-menu').addClass('menu-container').html(
    $('<ul/>').addClass('popup-menu').attr('id', 'dataset-menu').append(
        $('<div/>').text(dataset.label).addClass('menu-item')
    )
);
```

and here's [the live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hpzeX/1/).

Comment: +1, This should be classified the "proper" way, as it's compartmentalizing functionality and avoiding any kind of intervening (albeit script variables, cookie values, etc.)